# Text with in the html tag providing the tag name with attribute

Tags: java, regex

I have a string looks like this-

```
  <h3 class="media__title"> 
  <a class="media__link" href="/news/world-europe41644527" rev="video|headline">
  The equestrian champion with no legs                                                         
  </a> </h3>
```

And I tried to read and get the text within the h3 tags using this 
pattern

```
 String regex = <h3>(.+?)</h3>
```

The code I'm using

```
 private ArrayList<String> getValues(String resource) {
    final ArrayList<String> values= new ArrayList<>();
    final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        values.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return values;
}
```

This code will work if I remove the `class=media__title`  attribute from the h3 tags. I tried changing the regex to this

```
String regex = <h3 class=\"medial__title\">(.+?)</h3>
```

and still no progress. Can someone tell me what should be changed in this regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String regex = <h3 (.*)>((.|\s)+?)<\/h3>
```

The main problem with your approach is that the . character does not match line terminators.

Explained:

```
<h3 (.*)> matches an opening h3 tag together with all attributes contained (you could also use different patterns if you are interested in the attributes themselfs)

((.|\s)+?) match everything inside the h3 tag (.|s) means everything ("everything but line terminators or whitesaces")

<\/h3> the closing h3 tag (escaped because / is a regex delimiter)
```

Keep in mind that now the group you're looking for is the second group, not the first

Comment: how to provide attribute and value of the html to this regex pattern. i want to consume h3 tags with `class="media__title"` attribute. thanks

Comment: Something like this? <h3 class="media__title">((.|\s)+?)<\/h3>
Link: https://regex101.com/r/o8mHwh/1, or if you wish to match all h3's that have the class="media__title" and/or other attributes try this:<h3(.*)class="media__title"(.*)>((.|\s)+?)<\/h3>